# How to display images by using listview in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, listview

Iam using a listview to display table contents from mysql DB,thats working fine.But i want to know how to display images inside each column in listview table.

```
<LayoutTemplate>
<table runat="server" id="table1">

   <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">

     <th class="tablehead">
        Movie Name
    </th>
     <th class="tablehead">
        Movie Genre
    </th>
    <th class="tablehead">
        Image
    </th>
</table>
</LayoutTemplate>

 <ItemTemplate>
<tr id="Tr2" runat="server" class="tablerw">
 <td style="background-color:#EEEEEE;width:100px;" class="tablerw"> <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server"
   Text='<%#Eval("MovieName") %>' /></td>
 <td style="background-color:#EEEEEE;width:100px;"> <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server"
          Text='<%#Eval("movieGenre") %>' /></td>
    <td style="background-color:#EEEEEE;width:100px;"> <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"
          Text='<%#Eval("Image") %>' /></td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Aspx.cs

```
public  DataTable GetAllmoviedet()
     {
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        try
         {
         string connString = cnst.cnstrin();
         string query = "SELECT `moviemaster`.`MovieName`,`moviemaster`.`image`,`moviemaster`.`MovieGenre`";
          MySqlDataAdapter ma = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connString);
          DataSet DS = new DataSet();
          ma.Fill(dt1);
          return dt1;
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
      }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
      {
        var tbl = GetAllmoviedet();
        ListView1.DataSource = tbl;
        ListView1.DataBind();
        GetAllmovie1();
     }
    }
```

By using these codes,i can manage to get image name only.So i need to display exact image instead of names.How can i possible this?any help?

Comment: Does `Image` contains the path or binary data ?

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal:all images are inside a folder named images.

Comment: Then use this `<img src='<%# "YOUR_DIRECTORY_PATH" + Eval("Image") %>' />`

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal:how to bind each image name?.In the listview tables i need to display mouvie names and corresponding images.

Comment: Just clarify you want to bind a image or just image name.

Comment: @Unnikrishnan.S Save Imagepath(Path where your image physically located in server) with MovieName in two different columns in your database table. After that bind the image name as you bind the movie name inside listview.

Comment: @Jaihind:can you please give me a sample code?

Comment: Use image tag to bind image instead of binding in label text.

Comment: @Unnikrishnan.S : http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1084/saving-images-into-the-database-in-aspnet-and-displaying-to-the-gridvi.  This may help you